# How do you force an electron app to have a single instance?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to keep my electron app from being able to start more than one window at a time. I've already tried this, but it makes the first window opened close itself instead of the second window opened, and it completely stops working for the third window:

```
app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
app.on('second-instance', () => {
    app.quit();
});
```

The older `app.makeSingleInstance` also throws an error since it's deprecated. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: [the example in the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelockadditionaldata) looks like the best pattern to follow! I.e. call `app.quit()` when `app.requestSingleInstanceLock()` returns false

---

From [the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-second-instance):

> This event will be emitted inside the **primary** instance of your application when a second instance has been executed and calls app.requestSingleInstanceLock().

I.e. this is why `app.quit()` shuts the first window.

> ... Usually applications respond to this by making their primary window focused and non-minimized.

So if `win` is the instance of `BrowserWindow` that your main process opened, you could do:

```
win.show()
win.focus()
```

I believe you could also do nothing in the 'second-instance' handler: the event is just for information, telling you that the user has tried to open your app a second time.

Comment: @GreysonR. Thanks: I just saw that is what the app.requestSingleInstanceLock() docs say to do, so I've updated my answer with a link to that.